# Problems with Javascript (AddInput)

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
function addInput() {
if (fields != 3) {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input type='text' value='' /><br />";
fields += 1;
} else {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Only 3 fields allowed.";
document.form.add.disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input type="button" onClick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add input field" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is if submit this code, how can i know name for each input text that had been added.

Thanks for helping, I'm newbies in JS.

Comment: On another note, create a separate element and id for the notification of "Only 3 fields allowed", otherwise they will see this message appended over and over to the bottom of the element with id 'text' with your current code.

Comment: question is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign them id's and names when you create them in your JavaScript code. The following example gives each input the ids and names "field1", "field2" and "field3" when they are created:

```
<script language="javascript">
    fields = 0;
    function addInput() {
        if (fields != 3) {
            fields += 1;
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input id='field" + fields + "' name='field" + fields + "' type='text' value='' /><br />";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Only 3 fields allowed.";
            document.form.add.disabled=true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then, you can either call them by name with something like:

```
var myFirstField = document.getElementById('field1');
```

And on a postback, you can reference their names if the form is submitted to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your name field to an html array like

```
<input type="button" onClick="addInput()" name="add[]" value="Add input field" />
```

then when you submit your code you get an array of add.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = 0,
    button = document.getElementById( 'button' ),
    text = document.getElementByIs( 'text' ),
    addInput = function() {
        if( fields !== 3 ) {
            fields += 1;
            text.appendChild( '<input type="text" value="" name="fields" /><br />' );
        } else {
            text.appendChild( '<br />Only 3 fields allowed.' );
            document.form.add.disabled = true;
        }
    };
if( window.addEventListener ) {
    button.addEventListener( 'click', addInput, false );
} else if( window.attachEvent ) {
    button.attachEvent ( 'onclick', addInput );
} else {
    button[ 'onclick' ] = addInput; 
}
```